# DownloadManager for Android to update progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, download-manager

I was wondering if anybody knew how to update progress Bar in the application while attempting to download file using download manager for android?

Please share your ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a look at AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

and you can show the `ProgressBar` in `onPreExecute()` do the task in `doInBackground()` and hide the `ProgressBar` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I did with asyncTask, I need to continue the downloading even if the device restart as downloadManager does.